# Can Demons and Devils Starve to death?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So we've got a small pocket of dwarves (aka vampires!) walled away safely, and my fort is infested with FUN (aka demons and devils!). They've killed 3 sieges now. Will they ever starve to death, or do I actively have to do something to get rid of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only Dwarves and Tame animals can starve to death (at the moment, herbivores only).

The only way to kill them is with a trained army of vampire super soldiers - pity they don't drink (Alcohol dependency makes Dwarven Vampires move like Dwarven Syrup).